# How to return a bitmap image from a custom assembly to an SSRS report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, bitmap

I am using the QRCode4CS class (http://qrcode4cs.codeplex.com/releases/view/74015) to generate QR codes.

I can use the following code to successfully return a bitmap image to a picturebox in a Windows Form Application.

```
public class CreateQRCodeClass
{
    public static Image CreateQRCodeImage(string inputString)
    {
        QRCode4CS.QRCode qrcode = new QRCode4CS.QRCode(new QRCode4CS.Options(inputString));
        qrcode.Make();
        Image canvas = new Bitmap(86, 86);
        Graphics artist = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
        artist.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int row = 0; row < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); col++)
            {
                bool isDark = qrcode.IsDark(row, col);

                if (isDark == true)
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
            }
        }
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 76, 86, 86);
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 76, 0, 86, 86);
        artist.Dispose();
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

In trying to adapt the same code (below) to display a QR code in an SSRS report I get the error "There is an error on line 1 of custom code: [BC30311] Value of type 'System.Drawing.Image' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte.'

Here is the custom code I am using.

```
Public Function QRCode(ByVal RetailerId As String) as Byte()
     Return QRCode4CSCreateQRCode.CreateQRCodeClass.CreateQRCodeImage(RetailerId)
End Function
```

Here is the revised custom assembly.

```
public class CreateQRCodeClass
{
    public static byte[] CreateQRCodeImage(string inputString)
    {
        QRCode4CS.QRCode qrcode = new QRCode4CS.QRCode(new QRCode4CS.Options(inputString));
        qrcode.Make();
        Image canvas = new Bitmap(86, 86);
        Graphics artist = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
        artist.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int row = 0; row < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); col++)
            {
                bool isDark = qrcode.IsDark(row, col);

                if (isDark == true)
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
            }
        }
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 76, 86, 86);
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 76, 0, 86, 86);
        artist.Dispose();

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        canvas.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] imagedata = null;
        imagedata = ms.GetBuffer();

        return imagedata;
    }
}
```

What data type can I successfully return to SSRS to display the image?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

You have to convert the bitmap image to a byte array to display it in SSRS.

This is what the revised code looks like that can be used with SSRS.

```
    public static Byte[] ReturnByteArray(string inputString)
    {
        QRCode4CS.QRCode qrcode = new QRCode4CS.QRCode(new QRCode4CS.Options(inputString));
        qrcode.Make();
        Image canvas = new Bitmap(86, 86);
        Graphics artist = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
        artist.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int row = 0; row < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < qrcode.GetModuleCount(); col++)
            {
                bool isDark = qrcode.IsDark(row, col);

                if (isDark == true)
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 2 * row + 10, 2 * col + 10, 2 * row + 15, 2 * col + 15);
                }
            }
        }
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 76, 86, 86);
        artist.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 76, 0, 86, 86);
        artist.Dispose();

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        canvas.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imagedata = null;
        imagedata = ms.GetBuffer();

        return imagedata;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask how you included the DLL inside the rdl report??